# Initializing 2d vector in C++ compile error: wrong intepretation of compiler

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have the following code.

```cpp
constexpr int w=50;
constexpr int h=50;
struct Canvas {
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> net( w, std::vector<char>(h) );
    void clear(const char clear_char = ' ') {
        for (int i = 0; i < net.size(); ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < net[i].size(); ++j)
                net[i][j] = clear_char;
    }
    void draw_circle(const Brush& brush, const int cx, const int cy, const int r){
        static int c = 0;
        for (double i = 0; i <= 6.28; i += 0.02) {
            int y = round(0.54*r * sin(i))+cy;
            int x = round(r * cos(i)) + cx;
            if (c >= 0 && c <= 1)
                net[y][x] = brush.outline;

            else
                net[y][x] = brush.fill;
        }
        if (c != 0 && r == 0) {
            c = 0;
        }
        else if(brush.fill!='\0'){
            ++c;
            draw_circle(brush, cx, cy, r - 1);
        }
    }
};
```

I wanted to create a 2D vector of chars (wxh dimensions), but my compiler points our the following error:

```
E0757: variable w is not a type name.
```

How to fix?

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan This much works fine. Can you provide complete code where you used that line.

Comment: I have provided

Comment: `(...)` initialization is not allowed for members at class scope. You have to use either `{...}` or `= ...`, e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<char>> net = std::vector<std::vector<char>>( w, std::vector(h) );`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW the loop ending in a floating point equality test is not a good idea since there can be minuscule direction errors that will make it stop one iteration too soon

Comment: That wasn't a very good compiler message. There may have been a better message in the Output tab. The Error List leaves stuff out to keep the list a short and sweet summary. Sometimes it leaves out too much. The Output tab leaves out nothing. Sometimes it buries the information you need in reams of diagnostic, but most of the time I find the complete information more useful than the summary.

Answer (score 0):

Your array size is fixed, so `std::array<>` could be used:

```
constexpr int w=50;
constexpr int h=50;
struct Canvas {
std::array<std::array<char,w>,h> net;
void clear(const char clear_char = ' ') {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
            net[i][j] = clear_char;
...
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: I agree, but I used std::vector in order to alter the size of vector later.